# using Saxon.net with Mono 2.10.8 on Linux?

Tags: xslt, mono, saxon

I'm getting this exception when trying to use Saxon.NET with Mono 2.10.8 on Linux in the
Processor() constructor:

```
[eric@farm228 MetaTemplateGenerator]$ mono bin/Debug/MetaTemplateGenerator.exe simple.xml

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for net.sf.saxon.Configuration ---> System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at java.lang.Class.desiredAssertionStatus () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at net.sf.saxon.Configuration..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Saxon.Api.Processor..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MetaTemplateGenerator.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for net.sf.saxon.Configuration ---> System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at java.lang.Class.desiredAssertionStatus () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at net.sf.saxon.Configuration..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Saxon.Api.Processor..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MetaTemplateGenerator.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[eric@farm228 MetaTemplateGenerator]$ which mono
/tools/linux/mono-2.10.8/bin/mono
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.saxonica.com/community/boards/3/topics/5417?r=5424#message-5424